# Question 1 in the appendix on CW complexes in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I am asked to show that a covering space of a CW-complex is also a CW-complex with cells projecting homeomorphically onto cells.

Do you have a reference for this question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is an approach you can take: Let $\pi:Y\to X$ be the covering map.  Let $X_n$ be the $n$-skeleton of $X$.  First, show that the restriction of $\pi$ to $Y_n=\pi^{-1}(X_n)$ is a covering map.  Then, using induction, show that $Y_n$ is a CW complex.

Comment: In @Aaron's suggestion note the main point is that the only coverings of spaces with trivial $\pi_1$ are the trivial ones, so since each cell is simply connected it lifts to a disjoint union of cells in the cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for a reference. The result was one of the basic facts on CW-complexes in JHC Whitehead's paper "Combinatorial Homotopy I". Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **55** (1949) 213--245. (It is result (N) on p.231.) A proof is also given in Massey's book on "Algebraic topology".

Comment: In the reference of Whitehead, does he also solve other exercises in the appendix of Hatcher? I want to complete most if not all of the exercises in Hatcher and Spanier (unless if they coincide of course), so references would be great, I don't it need for a course (I had already a course in Algebraic Topology which wasn't complete to my taste, this is why I am repeating Hatcher and also look to supplement these texts with other references).

Comment: I'll mention my own book "Topology and Groupoids" for a different slant on   1-dimensional homotopy ideas, but with no homology, which is given a new type of  account, using strict higher groupoids,  in a 2011  EMS Tract partially titled "Nonabelian Algebraic Topology", (NAT), see my web pages.  It is these broader comparisons which are of interest to me.. This new book does cover developments of  certain methodologies of JHCW. in "Combinatorial Homotopy II". I don't know if this helps.